# Bring data from the last day of the previous month beyond

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer and I would like to make a SELECT that brings all the products sold from the last day of the previous month (but only products sold from 4 pm on the last day of the previous month) to the current day (only until 8 am of the current day).

For example, today is 7/21/2022. If I run this query today, it should bring data from:

06/30/2022 above 16:00hrs -> 07/21/2022 until 08:00hrs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `TRUNC(value, 'MM')` to find midnight of the 1st day of the current month and then subtract 8 hours to find the start of the range and then use `TRUNC(value)` to find midnight of today and add 8 hours to find the end of the range:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  date_column >= TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM') - INTERVAL '8' HOUR
AND    date_column <= TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '8' HOUR;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `TRUNC` to get to the first day of a date's month. Then subtract one day and add sixteen hours. And it's again `TRUNC` that you use to get back to the beginning of a day (midnight) to which you can add eight hours.

```
select * 
from mytable
where dt >= trunc(sysdate, 'mm') - interval '1' day + interval '16' hour
  and dt < trunc(sysdate, 'dd') + interval '8' hour
order by dt;
```